# An explicit idiom for instantiating templated code - without including its source

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, idioms

A very common coding pattern in C and C++ for functions, ADTs and classes is to have:

- A header .h file with a declaration (of a function of a class).
- An implementation .cpp file with the actual code.

These are compiled into a separate object (shared or not). Other code, using the declared entity (let's call it 'foo'), includes the foo.h file, is compiled separately and then links against foo.o .

However, with a templated foo, this is not possible: Without specifying for which type an instantiation for required, foo.o is useless. What everyone seems to be doing is including the implementation code (what would normally be foo.cpp) in the same translation unit as the user code.

I would like to be able to avoid this, using some mechanism which does not require including foo.cpp . Ideally, this should work:

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main() {
    foo<int>();
}
```

foo.h:

```
template<typename T> void foo();
```

foo.cpp:

```
template<typename T> void foo() {
    // implementation here
}
```

To do so, I suppose I need some sort of a clever idiom, possibly involving my build mechanism and not just the source and header files, so that I do not need to include the implementation code, just the header. I was thinking perhaps something along the lines of the implementation file including some auto-generated header with lines such as

```
template foo<int>();
```

which would be parsing the object files for the instances they're missing (i.e. two compilation passes), or perhaps parsing the source (tweaking the compiler? enabling some auxiliary output?) ; can you suggest such an idiom? Or another alternative I have not considered?

**Note:** Of course, the whole point is that the code for the foo module (`foo.h`, `foo.cpp`) does not 'know' which instantiations are needed, e.g. does not know whether `main()` will use `foo<int>()` or `foo<unsigned char>()`.

Comment: The C++ standard used to have a feature for this (I think the `export` keyword was reserved for this), but AFAIK the only compiler that more or less correctly supported this feature was SGI's C++ compiler. This feature was later dropped.

Comment: @Axel - it was EDG (Edison Design Group) who implemented `export` then suggested removing it from the language.

Comment: So did the SGI compiler have EDG's front end? Because I remember using it (must have been around 1997/8) and waitung impatiently for it being implemented by gcc just to learn later that it was dropped.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong whatsoever with including the source. Just put it in the .h file.

Comment: @n.m.: I didn't say it was 'wrong'. But I want to encapsulate my implementation. I don't want to contaminate my main's translation unit with all sorts of junk from the implementation file.

Comment: You didn't say it's wrong, and then immediately said you don't want to do it. I see a contradiction here. Either it's wrong, or there's no reason to avoid it. You cannot encapsulate everything 100% in C++ anyway, there's all sort of junk you have to expose, private members and inline functions and whatnot. It's a limitation of the language, accept it or find a language that doesn't have one. There's no contamination of the source either, the main TU should only see `#include "foo.h"`. The preprocessed source has all sorts of junk but who cares?

Comment: @n.m.: I'm sorry, but I don't accept your dichotomy. You are entitled to your opinion about the inclusion of the implementation being innocuous.

Comment: Inclusion of sources is how C++ templates work. That's how they are designed to work. It took a lot of brilliant minds a lot of time to come up with the current system. It's not ideal but that's what we are able to achieve and that's what everyone does. You don't change the established system by asking others how to do that, you do it by designing a better system yourself. Good luck.

Comment: n.m.: If you believe my question is inappropriate, you can vote it down, but I really do not agree with your claims. You're misreading intention into exigency, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

It's explicit instantiation.

```
template foo<int>();
```

It says to compiler to make `foo` implemented for `int`. It's like that you write an implementation for `int` in your `.cpp` file. This is useful if you know what types will be used in future. It can reduce total compile time in your project, if you're using `foo<int>` in many translation units. For example:

File `FooBar.h`:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    T data;
    void func();
};

template<typename T> void foo();
```

File `FooBar.cpp`:

```
template <typename T>
void Bar<T>::func()
{
}

template <typename T>
void foo() {
}

// explicit instantiation

template class Bar<int>;
template class Bar<std::string>;
template foo<int>();
template foo<float>();
```

The main problem is, your `foo` and `Bar` as templated things have to used just with instantiated types. For example, `foo` is limited to `int` and `float`, and `Bar` is limited to `int` and `std::string`.

Comment: +1 Yes, but I think you should give advice on how to use it (ie put the implementation in a .cpp-file and add all the needed explicit instantiations).

Comment: @MM. - you forgot to mention what a pain in the ass this approach is, which is why nobody does it any more. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker: I've added a statement at the end, check it if it's the one you want or not. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my humor didn't get through. I didn't have anything in particular in mind. The thing is it's a maintenance nightmare, because every time you use a template you have to check (either by looking in the instances file or by compiling to see if there are errors) whether the corresponding instantiation is in the instances file. And that means **every** template that's used, including templates used by your template.

Comment: I think I must have not made my question clear enough. Explicit instantiation is what I suggested I could use, but the point is that foo.h and foo.cpp must not need to know which types are necessary - they need to be oblivious to the fact that main.cpp needs `foo<int>()` rather than `foo<long long>()`. Perhaps I should clarify that some more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for instantiation only, we don't even have to duplicate the signature:

```
template decltype(foo<int>) foo;
```

this doesn't make so much of a difference in this example, but it does if your signature is long and tedious.